# CoovaChilli, virus/spam checking?

Tags: anti-virus, networking

We run a network for about 200 computers or so that using CoovaChilli backed with a freeradius backend for authentication. A number of users seem to have viruses and spam problems, which is flooding the network.

Does anyone know if there is a way to:

1. Check if the incoming connections from a user are virus or spam
2. If user has spam/virus problems, kick them and put them into a walled garden
3. Possibly display a webpage to the user telling them how to install a virus scanner

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for Network Access Control (NAC) functionality. CoovaChilli doesn't have such functionality built-in. You could use an outboard NAC system, like the free [PacketFence](http://www.packetfence.org/) product, or some off-the-shelf NAC product.